# how to change the color of the object while keeping the original material in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Clicking an object with the mouse changes the color of the clicked object

When you select it again, I am making the color of the clicked object and turning it back to the original color of white.

Simply(change the selected object color)

```
Material mat = objectManager.ReturnMat(obj);
mat.color=color.white
```

Originally, if you made a uv map for each object, there was no problem even if you changed the mat.color in duplicate.

This time, an object without a uv map is used separately, so if mat.color is applied, the original color is

For example, in the uv map, the specified color is painted with uv, so it was not strange because it was overlaid even if the color was changed.

Objects without a uv map change color, so the original color is blown away.

I don’t know exactly about the shader or texture material

I ask you a question.

Is there a way to change the color without losing the original color of the object through these?

I don't know how many objects can be clicked, but if you save the material for each click, you can enter about one.

Emission is not naturally that color is overlap orignial color

Comment: i want to prioritize material color over uv map

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for such kind of additional info - edit & update your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @4RZG4 answer:

If it's a performance issue, you can make a `Dictionary<int, Color>` of Colors, and every time you change the `Color` of your object, save it on the list, with the correspondent `GameObject` ID.

When `GameObject` uses the saved `Color`, remove it from the Dictionary. This way you will only have the references of the currently changed Colors, instead of every one that can be potentially changeable.

Comment: I received a new feedback today, but if it overlaps with the uv map, the colors will be mixed, so I received a feedback saying not to overlap. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your post was kind of unclear and I don't quite understand what you want, but I assume that you want to keep the original color of the object after you have changed the color to something else.

Implementing this is fairly easy; Just save the material in the `Start` function like this:

```
void Start()
{
    Material Temp = mat;
}
```

Now the original material is stored in a variable named `Temp`.

If you want to return `mat` to its original value, you can do like this:

```
mat = temp;
```

Comment: I don't use this method because I can allocate and store more than 2,000 meshes like this.